# How to call a c# method of my windows store app from a background task in windows

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a background task in windows 8.1 metro style apps that constantly checking for internet by implementing  "IBackgroundTask" and made it to run only if internet is available. so my question is how can I call a C# method if the background Task is triggered.??
Here is my code for background task

```
public sealed class CheckInternet : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        //Check if BackGroudTask is already registered
        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = RegisterBackgroundTask(entryPoinnt, TaskName);
        task.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
        //SendWorkOrdersToServer();

       _deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have it invoke a callback? Raise an event? Asynchronous programming is a staple of Windows Store apps, program it like any other async operation.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you for the reply. I want to call another method in my main project if back ground task triggers an event. Since both are from different projects, my back ground task is unaware of those methods.

Comment: Then you need to either accept a callback (through a delegate) or raise an event. Does that make sense?